# Spree Rake import will work for one table but not another one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I was hoping someone could help with this,

I have the following rake file

```
require 'csv'

desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"

task :assigntaxon, [:filename] => :environment do
        CSV.foreach('assigntaxon.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
        Spree::Products_Taxons.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
end
```

when i do that I get a message

rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::Products_Taxons

however when I run the rake file below I have no problems importing

```
require 'csv'

desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"

task :taxon0, [:filename] => :environment do
        CSV.foreach('taxon0.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
        Spree::Taxonomy.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
end
```

I am trying to link spree product ids to spree taxon ids, could it be that you cannot import into the spree products_taxons table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree::Products_Taxons is not the name of a Spree model. The model that relates products and taxons is called [Spree::Classification](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/6c33db95b78dd1462513e4610a0565969417eddf/core/app/models/spree/classification.rb)